A weird issue (to me) with converting the dict values to a list in python (debugger)
I am not sure I can explain the issue better than a screenshot. Either I am severely underslept or I have lost it (or, both)

chunks is a list of dict. I am able to run len(list(chunks[0].values())) but I am not able to run what is going inside the len
Any help is much appreciated

If chunks is a dict, then what do you expect chunks[0] to do?

oh no .. i will correct the question. chunks a list of dicts. You can verify this from chunks[0].values() being dict values in the second line in the debugger

list is a special command in the debugger.  If you need to print a list, do
print(list(chunks[0].values()))

